# Logback log files are not created in the docker container

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile, logback

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to deploy an application in a docker container as a JAR.
The application itself during its work creates an additional folder with logs in the root of the project. I use logback as a logging tool.
Faced with the fact that the folder with logs is not created in the docker container, and the corresponding subfolders and files in them are not created in it. The default owner seems to be the root user.
Locally (without a container), the program successfully works on Windows, but not on Linux.
Can you please tell me where the problem might be?

The file "logback-spring.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <Level>INFO</Level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%green(%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %yellow([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level)  %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/slf4jlogback.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="ru.skillbox.socnetwork.logging.LoggingAspect" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The file "Dockerfile":

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=/build/libs/*.jar
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Information from the command line:

```
C:\Users\Kirill\Documents>docker exec -it container_name_example sh
/app # ls -l
total 90824
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      93001049 Jun 16 18:40 app.jar
/app #
```

Comment: For relative paths you need to be sure that the current working directory actually is what you expect.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , Please tell me more. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Is the output of `pwd` Just before launching the application the location you have the `logs` folder in?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , I’ll probably say that it’s not always (rather, it’s not a permanent place). The application has logic that deletes this folder and then recreates it.
In fact, I would like to know if there is a way to "extend" the permissions on the working directory where I have the JAR?
That is, I need the log folder to be constantly re-created next to the JAR.